# Occurrence of Empty list in using csv module in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, csv

This is a code in a book.

```
import csv
villains = [['Doctor', 'No'],
            ['Rosa', 'Klebb'],
            ['Mister', 'Big'],
            ['Auric', 'Goldfinger'],
            ['Ernst', 'Blofeld'],
            ]
with open('villains', 'wt') as fout:
    csvout = csv.writer(fout)
    csvout.writerows(villains)
with open('villains', 'rt') as fin:
    cin = csv.reader(fin)
    villains = [row for row in cin]
print(villains)
```

My result is

```
[['Doctor', 'No'], [], 
['Rosa', 'Klebb'], [], 
['Mister', 'Big'], [], 
['Auric', 'Goldfinger'], [], 
['Ernst', 'Blofeld'], []]
```

Expected result is

```
[['Doctor', 'No'], 
['Rosa', 'Klebb'], 
['Mister', 'Big', 
['Auric', 'Goldfinger'], 
['Ernst', 'Blofeld']]
```

But I have some empty list in my result. 
I don't understand why these are appearing.

**MY QUESTION**

1. What in my code makes the empty lists?
2. How to correct my code to obtain expected result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty lines are there because the generated file contains empty lines:

```
Doctor,No

Rosa,Klebb

Mister,Big

Auric,Goldfinger

Ernst,Blofeld
```

This can be remedied by adding `if row` when reading the file:

```
with open('villains', 'r') as fin:
    cin = csv.reader(fin)
    villains = [row for row in cin if row]

print(villains)
#  [['Doctor', 'No'], ['Rosa', 'Klebb'], ['Mister', 'Big'], ['Auric', 'Goldfinger'],
#  ['Ernst', 'Blofeld']]
```

Alternatively you can generate the file without blank lines by passing `newline=''` to `open`:

```
with open('villains', 'wt', newline='') as fout:
    csvout = csv.writer(fout)
    csvout.writerows(villains)
```

Comment: What makes empty lines in the generated file? When I check the file by notepad, there is no empty line.